# How to use Lookupqueue?

Tags: delphi, msmq, delphi-2007

I use Delphi 2007 and I try to find out how to ask Windows (XP, Server 2003 or 2008) if a named MSMQ queue is installed. I have found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it is in C++ so it is not easy to use from Delphi. Example, I have an installed queue named '.\private$\nctsinqueue'. It works fine to use it by:

```
var
  QueueInfo : IMSMQQueueInfo2;
begin
  QueueInfo := CoMSMQQueueInfo.Create;
```

The problem is that in some installations of Windows where my application is installed this queue does not exists. It depend of the preferences if a queue is needed. So I want to ask Windows if a named queue is installed and in that case I can go on with the code above.

**EDIT:**
Tried this code

```
function Test: Boolean;
var
  QueueInfo : IMSMQQueueInfo2;
begin
  Result := True;
  QueueInfo := CoMSMQQueueInfo.Create;
  QueueInfo.PathName := '.\private$\nonexistingqueue';
  FQueue := QueueInfo.Open(MQ_RECEIVE_ACCESS, MQ_DENY_NONE);
end;
```

And it raise an exception on the last line. I can of course have a try/except here and return False in that case but I don't like to have exceptionhandling for this. I want to ask WinApi or something if the queue exists. Queue.IsOpen that [kobik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937125/kobik) suggest only says if an existing queue is opened. It must of course exist before it can be opened.

**Edit2:**
I take a more practical approach to this, so I solved it with ini-files for my application.
It tries to open only if the queue is present in the ini-file.
Disadvantage is of course that the ini-file must be in sync with the queues in the system, but that part is rather static.

Comment: I'm not following your question. It seems you've left a few words out or something? "In some installations" means "on some versions of windows" or it means "machines where I don't have MSMQ components installed" or something else? You are asking for an alternative to calling `MQLocateBegin`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clarify the question. And the question is how to find out if a named queue is existing or not as simple as possible.

Comment: Are you asking for help translating the C++ into Delphi? How far have you got yourself? Have you checked the JEDI project to see if they have the necessary header translations?

Comment: Despite the label at the top of the referenced page, that code is plain old C. What problem are you having with it? It looks like s a bunch of variable declarations, assignment statements, and API function calls. It should be adaptable to any language, assuming you can read C.

Comment: look [here](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=47776) and [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/df/265224.html). so `if Queue.IsOpen then` Queue exists.

Comment: IsOpen only say if an existing queue is opened. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711386%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I want to know if the queue exists.

Comment: I have investigated it a bit more. my conclusion was don't bother. use `try catch` with `open`. all `msdn` examples I have seen used exception handlers. maybe someone else could come up with a better idea...

Comment: How about: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/07/31/checking-if-msmq-queues-exist-is-hard-work-so-should-you-bother.aspx

Comment: Seems like `MSMQQuery.LookupQueue` does not work with private queues. only with public.

Comment: That's right - it's an Active Directory lookup query which can only be used on objects published in AD so private queues by definition are excluded.

Comment: I solved it in the ini-file. Maybe not the best but it works...